# How to sync a database that exists in various (not networked) SQL Server 2005 instances

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a database application that runs on various independent servers. 
Each server runs an Instance of SQL Server 2005 with the same database. We would have a Master Server where that would be the definitive source of information and various "Client" Servers that would be distributed around (with no network connection of any kind). This Client Servers would return from time to time (lets say once a week) to be synchronized with the Master. Simply put the process would be.

1) Update the database on the master server with all the modifications from a client server (taking into account not overwriting changes made by the update process of a different client server [that would update the same master server])

2) Copy an updated version of the master server database to the client server.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check for [database replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(SQL.90).aspx). Check the [Master-Remote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152761(SQL.90).aspx) part too.

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Integration Services may help:

http://www.microsoft.com/sql/technologies/integration/default.mspx